# Speed up Nginx displaying website - Time to First Byte

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-12.04

I have an Nginx server with a few sites on, and some sites on the server are taking quite a while longer to transfer the first byte then some others. As far as I am aware, Nginx looks through each conf file in the sites-enabled folder until it finds the correct file, so all the  sites that have a conf file close to the top of this list have significantly faster Time to First Byte than those at the bottom of the list. Is there any way to make them all load just as fast?

I know there is a slim chance, but I thought it was worth asking nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not how nginx handles things.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/hash.html

> To quickly process static sets of data such as server names, map directive’s values, MIME types, names of request header strings, nginx uses hash tables. During the start and each re-configuration nginx selects the minimum possible sizes of hash tables such that the bucket size that stores keys with identical hash values does not exceed the configured parameter (hash bucket size). The size of a table is expressed in buckets. The adjustment is continued until the table size exceeds the hash max size parameter. Most hashes have the corresponding directives that allow to change these parameters, for example, for the server names hash they are server_names_hash_max_size and server_names_hash_bucket_size.

It definitely isn't going through those files for every pageview.

Comment: So why is it some sites on the server have a faster first byte time than others?

Comment: Are the sites all identical code and configuration?

Comment: Yes they all use the same software (magento) and have the same conf file, the only difference being the server names and root path. Also some sites are significantly bigger than others, but that shouldn't affect the first byte time right?

Comment: Sure it would. If they've got a lot more in the database, Magento and MySQL may well be doing much more work to render that first byte.